# Jade mixin trouble

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm using jade's mixin and got some trouble:

code:

```
  mixin renderLink(linkName,linkUrl,linkClass,other)
    - var active = req.url==linkUrl?'active':''
    li(class=[active,linkClass])
      a(href=linkUrl) #{linkName}
      #{other}

  ....
  .nav-collapse
    ul.nav
      +renderLink('HOME','/')
      +renderLink('CHAT','/chat',null,'span.badge.badge-warning 2')
```

what I want is:

```
li
  a(href="#") 
    CHAT
    span.badge.badge-warning 2
```

how to modify #{other} to get what I want?
thanks

**---thanks, use this:**

```
  mixin renderLink(linkName,linkUrl,linkClass)
    - var active = req.url==linkUrl?'active':''
    li(class=[active,linkClass])
      a(href=linkUrl) #{linkName}
        block
```

and got what I want:

```
<li class=" ">
  <a href="/chat">消息<span class="badge badge-warning">2</span></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well first of all, I'm assuming you want `CHAT` on the same line as `a` since you don't want a `<chat></chat>` element.

It's not documented (in the official docs), but what you want is to use a block. Try this:

```
mixin renderLink(linkName,linkUrl,linkClass,other)
  - var active = req.url==linkUrl?'active':''
  li(class=[active,linkClass])
    a(href=linkUrl) #{linkName}
      if block
        block

....
.nav-collapse
  ul.nav
    +renderLink('HOME','/')
    +renderLink('CHAT','/chat')
      span.badge.badge-warning 2
```

I'm not sure if the `if block` statement is necessary.

Comment: @Jonathan Ong, it looks like if block is most useful with "else" branch for providing some default layout whenever block has not been declared explicitly.